# any pdf reader has a book-mark feature?

Tags: windows, pdf-reader

Is there any software for **Windows** or **web based application** that would allow me to open pdf and before closing **create a bookmark** so I know where to 'open my book' next time?

I can see that there is a question from a linux user. I need windows version or web based application.

The best would be to mark exact paragraph, or even a word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adobe PDF Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) can do this.

Comment: that's great, what exact paragraph? word?

Comment: It restores to the last line that you were viewing @Radek

Comment: yes, you're right. I clicked the line I had in my mind. I didn't scroll there. Cool solved. Any web based application that does the same?

Comment: @Radek I'm not aware of any web based apps which can do this.

Answer (score 3):

[SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) does not create bookmarks per se but remembers where you were in a PDF when you close the app and opens to that page when you re-open.

Answer (score 2):

[Evince](http://live.gnome.org/Evince/Downloads) has a Win32 port.

Answer (score 1):

[Foxit](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/) is a Windows PDF-reader with bookmarks support (including creation and editing).
This feature is included even in the free version as can be seen in [this comparison-sheet](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/comparison_sheet.html) of their version.

Answer (score 1):

[Mobipocket Reader](http://www.mobipocket.com/en/DownloadSoft/default.asp?Language=EN) remembers your last page and also allows bookmarks so you can easily switch between selected passages. It's free and has links to many eBook sites if you want more.

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/products/digitaleditions/) also remembers the last page read. It's not great, but has some desirable features.